# Jquery Plugin simple Lightbox IE Bug

Tags: jquery, css, plugins

I downloaded and installed the Jquery Plugin simple Lightbox (http://dbrekalo.github.io/simpleLightbox/) on my website. Now I just discovered, that when I upload pictures in portrait, IE turns the pictures 90°:
Just found out there are all the classes from the plugin also supported by IE.  But if I open the picture directely it also displays in a 90° angle in IE but correctly not in Chrome

Has anyone experienced this before? Do I have to change that in my Apache Server?

Comment: Can you provide more details and a working example in jsfiddle or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, it has nothing to do with the Server or CSS. The picures which were uploaded still had some Exif-data with a 90° rotation of the picture.
I fixed it by rotating it to the wright angle and deleting all Exif-data from the picture:

```
function autoRotateImage($image) {
    $orientation = $image->getImageOrientation();

    switch($orientation) {
        case imagick::ORIENTATION_BOTTOMRIGHT: 
            $image->rotateimage("#000", 180); // rotate 180 degrees
            break;

        case imagick::ORIENTATION_RIGHTTOP:
            $image->rotateimage("#000", 90); // rotate 90 degrees CW
            break;

        case imagick::ORIENTATION_LEFTBOTTOM: 
            $image->rotateimage("#000", -90); // rotate 90 degrees CCW
            break;
    }

    // Now that it's auto-rotated, make sure the EXIF data is correct in case the EXIF gets saved with the image!
    $image->setImageOrientation(imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);
}

function fixuploadedimg($image) {
    autoRotateImage($image);//rotate and fix Exif rotation
    $image->stripImage();//remove all EXIF data

    //resize image if necessary
    $xWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
    $xHeight = $image->getImageHeight();
    if($xWidth > 1000)
    {
        $image->resizeImage(1000, ($xHeight*1000/$xWidth), imagick::FILTER_GAUSSIAN, 1); 
    }
    else if($xHeight > 1000)
    {
        $image->resizeImage(($xWidth*1000/$xHeight), 1000, imagick::FILTER_GAUSSIAN, 1); 
    }

    $image->writeImage($uploadimg_title);
}

function get_file_extension($file_name) {
    return substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
}


$img_ext_title = get_file_extension($_FILES['titelbild']['name']);
//$uploadimg_title_temp = $ordner.$foldername."/title_temp.".$img_ext_title;
$uploadimg_title = $ordner.$foldername."/title.".$img_ext_title;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['titelbild']['tmp_name'], $uploadimg_title)){ 
    $img_title = new Imagick($uploadimg_title);
    fixuploadedimg($img_title);
    $img_title->clear();
    $img_title->destroy();
}
else
{
    echo "upload failed";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you need to add some fix for Internet Explorer, so doing something like:

```
onShown: function(){
       if(isInternetExplorer){
           $('.ekko-lightbox').addClass('iefix');
       }
   }
});
```

But first you need to see why is turning 90deg in internet explorer, there should be some classes not being supported by IE, so I would suggest inspecting the element in IE, comparing it with chrome or the browser it's working, and then apply the fix in CSS to the class 'iefix', and then add the class with the above code mentioned.